# Web browser control in Windows form

Tags: winforms

How does the web browser control in windows form work ? Any body has any idea. Is there an inbuilt internet explorer engine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebBrowser, check out this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752085(VS.85).aspx